# What does this style of writing mean?

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Counter {
    (start: number): string;
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
    let counter = <Counter>function(start: number) {
        return start.toString();
    };
    counter.interval = 123;
    counter.reset = function() {
        this.interval = 0;
    };
    return counter;
}

let c = getCounter();
c(10);
c.reset();
c.interval = 5.0;
```

I want to know:

1. `(start: number): string;` a anonymous function here?
2. the meaning of `<Counter>` in

   ```
   let counter = <Counter>function(start: number) {
     return start.toString();
   };
   ```
3. I don't understand what `c` is in `let c = getCounter()`;

   It's not a object , not a class , and its type is `Counter` which means a `interface` (but why assigned to a function?) So is `c` an instance of Counter? And the interface is equal to function?

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html; `(start: number): string` means the interface describes a function type. `c` is a *function* at runtime; interfaces only exist before compilation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1st answer:**
 its the **call signature** (something like the constructor) and it means this interface is a function and when ever you implement it, it should have a function that get a number and returns a string and when you want to create an instance of your implementation you should call it.

**2nd answer:**
 that function is defining the interface constructor and return the instance of your interface implementation.

**3rd answer :**
 related to second answer the instance that created should be put in the variable.

I hope I explained it clearly